# Submit form Bootbox with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, bootbox

i'm developing a chat using php, bootbox and ajax to submit form, right, but i can't submit form with ajax!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#startchat").click(function(){
                bootbox.confirm("<center><form id='infos' method='POST' action=''>\
                        <p style='font-size:25px'>Formulário para Inicialização do Chat</p>\
                        Nome:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='text' name='nome'></input><br/><br/>\
                        Email:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='text' name='email'></input>\
                    </form></center>", function(result) {
                if(result){
                    $('#infos').submit();
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'post',
                            url: 'dateRecd.php',
                            data: 'nome=' + nome + '&email=' + email,

                                success: function(data){
                                    alert(nome+' e '+email);
                                }                               
                        });
                }
                });
            });

        });
```

Well, i need submit form to the next page **dateRecd.php** insert date and call this chat function  **chatWith(id,name)** with two parameters, that start the chat, Id and Name, they are fetched data in mySQL!

I don't where is wrong, firt time i'm using bootbox

```
<a href="javascript:void()" id="startchat">
                    <img src="banner.jpg">              
            </a>
```

Comment: You do realize that you're missing some `}` at the end of your code, right?

Comment: Sorry man, Copy and Paste, always have error!